# Process a string to insert key/value into a dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I have a string of the format "Position=10,IntraDay=20,Client=30,". I want to insert it into a dictionary e.g ,, should be my key value pair of the dictionary. How to do it in an easy way .And vice versa too.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-code, since you can surely figure the exact steps out yourself:

> *dict* ← **new** Dictionary〈string, string〉
>   *parts* ← split *input* at `','`
>   **for each** *part* **in** *parts*:
>       *key*, *value* ← split *part* at `'='`
>       add (*key*, *value*) to *dict*

That'd be the most trivial way. It's not necessarily efficient, it may break, depending on your data, but since we don't know anything else here, it might just as well work. You could also make the dictionary accept `int` values and parse the integer beforehand.

Comment: Can u give an example how to split the int values?

Comment: The example would be at http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+string+split

Answer (score 1):

This is an example code of @Joey 's Pseudo-code:

```
//Your string (note: I have removed ending comma of your sample string)
string mystring = "Position=10,IntraDay=20,Client=30";

//Your dictionary
Dictionary<string, string> mydic = mystring.Split(',')
                                  .ToDictionary(s => s.Split('=')[0], 
                                                s => s.Split('=')[1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for the following:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string,int>();
var Pairs =  "Position=10,IntraDay=20,Client=30,".Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var pair in Pairs)
{
     var p = pair.Split('=');
     dic.Add(p[0],Convert.ToInt32(p[1]));
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
private Dictionary<String, Int32> ProcessInputString(string str) { 
    var Dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
    var Entries = str.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach(var Entry in Entries) {
        var EntryData = Entry.Split('=', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var Key = EntryData[0];
        var Value = Convert.ToInt32(EntryData[1]);
        if(!Dictionary.ContainsKey(Key))
            Dicationary[Key] = Value;
    }
    return Dictionary;
}
```